# How to get nodeName of html document elements by Awesomium ExecuteJavascriptWithResult?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, awesomium

I created a new WPF project, and added a Awesomium 1.6.4 WebControl to it. Now I want to Retrieving the element under the mouse and show it in the textbox. Then, I added this code but it didn't work correctly.

```
void webcontrol_LoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e){
    textBox1.Text = webcontrol.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {var nodename = e.srcElement.nodeName; return nodename;}()").ToString();
}
```

Comment: Read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), please...

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with this code:

```
void wc_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        JSValue ele = webcontrol.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"document.elementFromPoint(" + e.GetPosition(webcontrol).X.ToString() + "," + e.GetPosition(webcontrol).Y.ToString() + ").outerHTML");
        textBox1.Text = ele.ToString(); 
    }
```